# How do I use sizzle like jQuery do for selecting and performing actions to the selected elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, sizzle

I am creating a JavaScript library like jQuery.
I was using simple `querySelector()`  method to select elements.
Eg. `$(element).method()`.

Then I found jQuery uses sizzle.
I also wanted to use sizzle .
But how can I use sizzle like jQuery do, It don't have documentation in this topic .

So simply , I  want that I use sizzle selector like this `$(element)` where `SizzleSelctor(element)` is converted to `$Selctor(element)` and I could add methods to function or sizzle selector and apply to selected elements.
Like `$(element).addClass("how to do this");`

Comment: Go through the jQuery source to see how they use it. Sounds like you might just as well use jQuery itself

Comment: Ok  . But please help , if you are having any solutions :).